# MVC DropDownListFor() - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm very confused by this, and I feel like I must be missing something incredibly obvious.

I have a view model that contains the following properties:

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CourseList { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I use the `Html.DropDownListFor()` helper method in the following way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseId, Model.CourseList)
```

This works on initial page load.  When I click submit however, and there's an error in the form somewhere, my controller tries to load the form view again to show the errors, and I receive this exception:

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'CourseId' is of type
'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

With the following line highlighted:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseId, Model.CourseList)
```

My question is simple: *why*?  Why should `CourseId` need to be an `IEnumerable` of `SelectListItem` in order to function as the first parameter in that method?  I've checked all of the available signatures for that method and *none* of them take an `IEnumerable` of `SelectListItem` as the first parameter.  So what gives?

Comment: @stripthesoul no, that's not the problem. The error is complaining about `CourseId` which is an `int`, and needs to be in order to be used as the first parameter.  I figured it out anyhow, see my answer if you're curious.

Comment: @stripthesoul it's also worth mentioning that `List` implements `IEnumerable`, so using `List` where `IEnumerable` is requested is just fine.

Comment: It is a very odd that the error was not indicative of the real issue. Agreed. I stand corrected.

Comment: Yeah weird - thank you very much for having a look though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... ugh.  I don't know why *that* was the error I was getting, but the problem was that my `CourseList` was not being populated the second time through and was therefore null.  Fixing that fixed the error.

As for why the error message was so off-base, I'm still not sure.

Comment: The reason has to do with the ViewState and the way that MVC deals with null parameters to helpers.  Because the list was null, it tried to find the list based on the ViewState, which is based on the CourseId.